# Why do we want to operate at dew point or bubble point when doing flash calculations?

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-engineering

I'm trying to dimension a flash drum for a separation between water and isobutane. I now the total inlet flow (F), the composition of the inlet flow ($z_1$ for isobutane and $z_2$ for water) and the total pressure (P). My supervisor told me that if my inlet flow to the flash was gas I would want my flash drum to operate at dew point temperature. And vice versa I would like my flash drum to operate at bubble point if my inlet flow was liquid. Therefore I have to do a dew or bubble point calculation for the temperature. Why is this true? According to her this is something you always want you flash drum to operate at.

If I had known the outlet molar flow of vapor (V) and liquid (L) I would have used the following iterative model:

1. We know F, $z_i$, P, V and L
2. Guess T
3. Calculate $P_1°$ and $P_2°$ from a model (as an example Antoines equation)
4. Calculate $x_i=\frac{Fz_i}{V\frac{P_i°}{P}+L}$
5. Check if $\sum x_i=1$. If not true redo from point 2. If true you have found the flash temperature.

However this isn't possible since I don't know the outlet flows V and L.

So to recap my question is: Why does the flash need to operate at dew or bubble point temperature? Is it because it's most cost  efficient to do so? Do I get the best separation at this temperature (and if so why)? Any other reasons why this temperature is the best to operate at?

Comment: Well, the flash is going to take place at equilibrium between the vapor and liquid.  So you are setting the drum pressure (which is less than the feed pressure) and determining the split between liquid and vapor under the condition that the enthalpy change across the inlet is zero.  You adjust the drum pressure to get the split you want.